# WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter add to root context in non Servlet 3.0 container

Tags: java, spring-security, annotations

I have an example web app which I am using as a sample to convert an existing *servlet 2.4* application to move from XML based Security config to the new Java config based style as described here. [Spring Security Java Config Preview](http://spring.io/blog/2013/07/03/spring-security-java-config-preview-web-security/#web-security-hellowebsecurityconfiguration)

My security configuration is as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Slf4j
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

public WebSecurityConfig() {
    log.info("init");
}

@Override
protected void registerAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
}

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**");
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  http
    .authorizeUrls()
      .antMatchers("/","/home").permitAll() 
      .antMatchers("/secure/**").hasRole("USER")
      .anyRequest().authenticated()
      .and()
  .formLogin() 
      .loginUrl("/login") 
      .permitAll();
}
}
```

The problem is that the documentation/examples are based on servlet 3.0 specs, which do not use web.xml

The documentation uses AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer but I *cannot* use this in a servlet 2.4 container.

I bootstrap my MVC app using **web.xml** like this:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>my-spike</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>
           org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>com.example.config.WebMvcConfig</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```

So the question is how to add my WebSecurityConfig to the root application context in web.xml, or in Java code?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to configure it through `ContextLoaderListener` this way:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value> package.WebSecurityConfig</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
    <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
</context-param>
```